# Python Check if Variable is Duplicated in list

Tags: python, list, variables, duplicates

I want to see if there is a way to tell if a variable has an equivalent variable in a list.

```
a = 'hi'

b = 'ji'

c = 'ki'

d = 'li'

e = 'hi'

letters = [a, b, c, d, e]
```

Is there a way to check if any variable(`a`) is equal to any other variable(`e`). In this case return `True`. Is there a quicker way than instead just listing out all the comparative sentence combinations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using the following -

```
len(letters) != len(set(letters))
```

When you convert a list to set, it removes duplicate elements from the list, so if any element is there more than once, in letters, the length of `set(letters)` would be less than the length of the original list , and the above condition would return `True`.

---

Example/Demo -

```
In [9]: a = 'hi'

In [10]: b = 'ji'

In [11]: c = 'ki'

In [12]: d = 'li'

In [13]: e = 'hi'

In [14]: letters = [a, b, c, d, e]

In [15]: len(letters) != len(set(letters))
Out[15]: True

In [16]: letters = [a,b,c,d]

In [17]: len(letters) != len(set(letters))
Out[17]: False
```

Comment: Is there any way to return the duplicate variable?

Comment: For that you can use `collections.Counter` , it will count the number of elements in letters, and then you can take elements that have more than 1 count.

Comment: I would suggest looping the array and create a dict using the hash of the item (string in this case). You can also identify duplicates in the loop.